# Jenkins save configure error: Mailformed GitHub Plugin configuration

Tags: jenkins

I am getting the above issue in Jenkins 1.6.1.7 on Windows, what's the solution? This link doesn't mention how to resolve it: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20123

Thanks
Jirong

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with GitHub plugin, but JIRA plugin, upgrade to v2.0.3 resolved this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30242.